# Might this script delete the file if fails?

Tags: bash, shell-script, sed

I suspect that the following script, executed by `root`, under certain conditions, deletes `/etc/hostapd.conf`:

```
#!/bin/bash    
CONFIG_FILE=/etc/hostapd.conf

read mac_addr < /sys/class/net/wlan0/address
mac_addr_no_colon=`echo $mac_addr | tr -d ":"`
mid_mac_addr=${mac_addr_no_colon:6}

new_ssid=Mark_$mid_mac_addr

sed "s/^ssid=.*/ssid=$new_ssid/" "$CONFIG_FILE" > /tmp/temp.x
mv /tmp/temp.x "$CONFIG_FILE"
```

Even if I ran this script hundreds of times, someone else reported that `/etc/hostapd.conf` was not found on its system and this is the only script I wrote that access to `/etc/hostapd.conf` for writing.

Is there any problem in this approach that might lead to such a behavior?

### UPDATE

Following the suggestion I changed the script as follow:

```
#!/bin/bash

CONFIG_FILE=/etc/hostapd.conf

mac_addr_no_colon="$(tr -d ':' < /sys/class/net/wlan0/address)"
mid_mac_addr=${mac_addr_no_colon:6}

new_ssid=Mark_$mid_mac_addr
sed -i "s/^ssid=.*/ssid=$new_ssid/" "$CONFIG_FILE"
```

Comment: Side note: `sed` has the `-i` switch for in-place editing, and you could skip a read-echo with `mac_addr_no_colon="$(tr -d ':' < /sys/class/net/wlan0/address)"`, but I don't see a path that would either delete or empty out a non-empty hostapd.conf.

Comment: @Mark: Do you have permissions to edit the file as non-root? Most likely you would need sudo permissions to write to it

Comment: @Inian, sorry I didn't say the script is executed as root.

Comment: Yes.  Whether or not the `sed` works, it nevertheless replaces the `hostapd.conf` file.

Comment: @steve, I replaced the `mv` command with the in-place substitution for `sed`. Is this way more robust?

Comment: @steve, but if `sed` fails, `/tmp/temp.x` is not created and then `mv` should fail too. I'm not saying it was ok, I'm just wondering how `hostapd.conf` would be replaced.

Comment: If sed fails, `/tmp/temp.x` *is* created. Example : try `sed 's/foo/bar/' nosuchfile >x`.  You'll see that file `x` is created each time.

Comment: Go it, but this will create an empty file. If this was the problem also `hostapd.conf` will be empty. Instead the problem is the file is actually *removed*.

Comment: Are you sure the file existed? I don't have `/etc/hostapd.conf` on my system, for example. Can the user confirm that the file used to be there on their system?

Comment: I don't quite know how `mv` would work on completely full root partition (all inodes used up). Is it possible that it would unlink the destination file and then not be able to allocate the needed inode to create the new file?

Comment: @terdon, yes because the rootfs is created from a custom Linux image and it contains the file for sure.

Comment: @Kusalananda I'm 99% sure that I've checked this at some point to confirm that the unlinking is only done after the new file has been created. Not 100% sure though...

Comment: @Mark why don't you place an AND (&&) conditional between sed and mv commands.

Comment: @RakeshSharma, in the updated version I remove the `mv` command completely. In any case feel free to propose an answer with your solution!

Comment: Did the problem disappear with the updated script?